# Xcode with Pod: Double-quoted include "ph.b" in framework header

Tags: xcode, firebase, frameworks, cocoapods

This error appears when I upgrade xcode to 12

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when you upgrade to xcode 12.The upgrading will change **Quoted Include in Framework header** to **Yes**:
[image: picture of interface]

SO you you should change it back to **No**